# How can I tag friends in uploaded photo using facebook php SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm doing this to create an album and upload a photo to user's profile:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => $statusFinal);
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($imagePath);
$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Is it possible to tag user friends? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and described in [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags)

Comment: ok, but I need an example in php or something that I can work with the code above.

Comment: @Bagata: it would be the similar request of `api()` method. Just try anything and update your question

Comment: @Bagata: so write **the same** for tagging. Just replace an endpoint to `PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID` (as it specified in documentation)