# How can I tag a user in the caption of a photo uploaded using Facebook's PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The question says it all. I followed this tutorial:

http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/12/upload-photos-to-facebook-fan-page.html

And I managed to do it. Now I want it so that whenever someone uploads a photo, the user is tagged in the caption of the photo--just in the caption, so anyone viewing my page can know who the user was that uploaded the picture. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been answered here: [How can I tag friends in uploaded photo using facebook php SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166292/how-can-i-tag-friends-in-uploaded-photo-using-facebook-php-sdk)

Like its stated there check the documentation for how to use tags here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags

Just doing this in my head from scratch (not tested)

```
$photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
$argstag = array('to' => $user);
$datatag = $facebook->api('/' . $photo['id'] . '/tags', 'post', $argstag);
```

Comment: I found that link when I was doing research earlier. Can you please provide me with the code as I am still a newbie? Thanks.

Comment: Hi I added your above code to:


$photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
  $argstag = array('to' => $user);
  $datatag = $facebook->api('/' . $photo['id'] . '/tags', 'post', $argstag);
  if( is_array( $photo ) && !empty( $photo['id'] ) ){
   echo '<p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$photo['id'].'">Click here to watch this photo on Facebook.</a></p>';
  }
 }

and it gave the the following error:

atal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) null does not resolve to a valid user ID thrown

Comment: you need to define $user with the facebook users id

Comment: Can you provide me the code please? Sorry if I am being too cheeky :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780416/how-get-facebook-user-id-from-my-application